# 'HtmlAgilityPack' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Net.Http'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, html-agility-pack

I get the error 'HtmlAgilityPack' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Net.Http' when trying to install the HtmlAgilityPack NuGet package. I have completely uninstalled and re-installed NuGet, there is no update available for the NuGet Package Manager (I am on version 2.8.60318.667) and I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Updating/Re-installing NuGet doesn't seem to work.

Yes I have looked at other threads but can't find a solution that will work for me.

Comment: To fix the issue, an earlier version of HtmlAgilityPack needs to be installed, using the console command "Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.4.0". This goes for any other package with this issue

Comment: @jack_allen you should post this as the answer.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the issue, an earlier version of HtmlAgilityPack needs to be installed, using the console command "Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.4.0". This goes for any other package with this issue